# Inequality: $\sum_{i} \frac1{\alpha_i} \ge n^2$

Tags: inequality

$\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ are positive reals whose sum does not exceed one. It is required to prove that:

$$\sum_{i} \frac1{\alpha_i} \ge n^2$$

I would show my work, but I am certain that it does not offer any insight because I feel that there is just a trick that should be used, and I'm not seeing it.

Thank you.

Comment: $AM \geq HM$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [arithmetic-harmonic mean inequality](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality), we may conclude that
$$\frac{\sum \alpha_i}{n}\ge \frac{n}{\sum 1/\alpha_i}$$
We rearrange this to get $$\sum \frac{1}{\alpha_i}\ge \frac{n^2}{\sum \alpha_i}$$
Since $\sum \alpha_i \le 1$, the desired inequality folows.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $x_i = \alpha_i^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $y_i = \alpha_i^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ for $i = 1,2,\ldots,n$. By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$\vert \langle x, y \rangle \vert \leq \|x\|_2\|y\|_2$$
which is
$$\vert \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i \vert^2 \leq (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2)(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2)$$
and therefore
$$n^2 = \vert \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^{\frac{1}{2}}\alpha_i^{-\frac{1}{2}} \vert^2 \leq (\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i)(\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^{-1}) = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^{-1}$$